# why isn't this caesarian shift working

Tags: java, char

```
private static String shift(String p, int shift){
    String s = "";
    int len = p.length();
    for(int x = 0; x < len; x++){
        char c = (char)(p.charAt(x) + shift);
        if (c == ' '){ // this right here isn't working
            s += " ";
        } else if (c > 'z'){
            s += (char)(p.charAt(x) - (26-shift));
        }
        else {
            s += (char)(p.charAt(x) + shift);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

example output: qer$hyhi ( the "$" used to be a space ). Why doesn't the space simply stay a space like it should? instead it still follows the conversion process.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the already shifted character to space.

There are several ways to fix this bug, one of them is the following (fixing some other minor issues):

```
private static String shift(String p, int shift){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();  //better using a mutable object than creating a new string in each iteration
    int len = p.length();
    for(int x = 0; x < len; x++){
        char c = p.charAt(x);  //no need for casting
        if (c != ' '){ // this should work now
            c += shift;
            if (c > 'z'){ //we assume c is in the 'a-z' range, ignoring 'A-Z'
                c -= 'z';
            }
        } 
        s.append(c);
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: cannot upvote this enough! this was the perfect and an easy to understand solution! thank you very much!